# PHP PhantomJS unable to make screenshot directory writable

Tags: php, phantomjs, webpage-screenshot, writable, php-phantomjs

I am trying to capture a screen and save it locally. When I run the code it shoots me an error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\NotWritableException: Output file is not writeable by PhantomJs:

This is my code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$client = Client::getInstance();
// $client->getEngine()->setPath('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs');

$width  = 800;
$height = 600;
$top    = 0;
$left   = 0;

/** 
 * @see JonnyW\PhantomJs\Http\CaptureRequest
 **/
$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createCaptureRequest('http://jonnyw.me');
$request->setOutputFile('/screenshot/TEST.jpg');
$request->setViewportSize($width, $height);
$request->setCaptureDimensions($width, $height, $top, $left);

/** 
 * @see JonnyW\PhantomJs\Http\Response 
 **/
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

// Send the request
$client->send($request, $response);

?>
```

And this is my form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Files to Crop/Take Screenshot of URL</title>
</head>
<body> 

  <h1>TAKE SCREENSHOT OF URL WITH phantomjs <span style="color:red">[NOT WORKING YET!!!!]</span></h1>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="phantomjs.php">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="siteToCapture">Site to Capture</label><br />
      https://www.<input type="input" name="siteToCapture" id="siteToCapture" />.com
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="SCAN" />
    </div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Another interesting thing I noticed was if I removed the '/' before screenshot/TEST.jpg I receive a blank page with no errors and still no screenshot.

I have also created the screenshot folder in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you are trying to write screenshot to `/screenshot/` folder. And the path is absolute. So make sure you have `/screenshot/` folder in the root of your disk and script can write to it.

There are two kinds of paths: **absolute** and **relative**.

First one, is path that is starts from the root of your disk and it **always** starts from `/` character, like this: `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs`.

Second one is the path which *relative* to your current working dirrectory, it can starts with `./` characters, or `../`, or just `some/folder/`. So, in your case, if you have `screenshots` folder within your current working directory, you should specify output file like this:

```
$request->setOutputFile('./screenshot/TEST.jpg');
```

Notice the **dot** char at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry I should also clarify. I have the folder created already in the correct directory.

Comment: OP doesnt seem to know what absolute path is.

Comment: Maybe =). Updated my answer

Comment: AHhhh I see what you meant. The __DIR__ was giving the path outside of the current directory.